# Docker Tomcat7 container not always starting correctly

Tags: tomcat7, docker

I'm doing some tests with Docker and I have problem to start my tomcat7 container, it sometimes start correctly and sometimes not. Here's an example of several tries

```
fred@fred-Latitude-E6520:~/docker/test2$ docker.io run  tomcat7
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
   ...done.
May 04, 2014 5:31:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 04, 2014 5:31:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
May 04, 2014 5:31:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
May 04, 2014 5:31:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 04, 2014 5:31:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 886 ms
fred@fred-Latitude-E6520:~/docker/test2$ docker.io run  tomcat7
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
   ...fail!
fred@fred-Latitude-E6520:~/docker/test2$ docker.io run  tomcat7
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
   ...fail!
fred@fred-Latitude-E6520:~/docker/test2$ docker.io run  tomcat7
 * Starting Tomcat servlet engine tomcat7
   ...done.
May 04, 2014 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 04, 2014 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
May 04, 2014 5:32:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
May 04, 2014 5:32:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
May 04, 2014 5:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 833 ms
```

My Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
# Update Ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
# Add oracle java 7 repository
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN apt-get -y update
# Accept the Oracle Java license
RUN echo "oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 boolean true" | debconf-set-selections
# Install Oracle Java
RUN apt-get -y install oracle-java7-installer
# Install tomcat
RUN apt-get -y install tomcat7
RUN echo "JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle" >> /etc/default/tomcat7
EXPOSE 8080
# Start Tomcat, after starting Tomcat the container will stop. So use a 'trick' to keep it running.
CMD service tomcat7 start && tail -f /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out
```

When it fails, how can I see what went wrong ?

Is there some kind of timeout for Docker startup ? If my container does not start within x seconds it's considered failed by Docker ?

Answer (score 1):

when it fails do:

```
docker logs $(docker -q -a -l)
```

and that will tell you why it failed.

I think the problem might be that tomcat does not run in the foreground so your docker container ends, you might want to try running tomcat under supervisor and put:

```
CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

as your command.

This will tell supervisor to run in the foreground and it will run tomcat for you.  You can find a lot of tomcat supervisor example confs with a quick google.  It should be very easy to do.

EDIT:

Alternatively, run tomcat in the foreground with

```
tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run
```

and that should have the same affect, so your cmd would look like this:

```
CMD ["<path/to/tomcat>/bin/catalina.sh", "run"]
```

hope this helps